# Guidelines for creating interactive visualisations?

Tags: information-visualization

Does anyone know any guidelines in creating interactive visualisations for the exploration of datasets?

I can find lots of material on why particular instances are good or bad, but the actual design process of designing an interactive visualisation seems to be a black art.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben Shneiderman constantly repeats the mantra of [Overview first, zoom and filter, then details-on-demand](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/nabhcs/abstracts/shneiderman.html).  Here are some [more references](http://www.infovis-wiki.net/index.php/Visual_Information-Seeking_Mantra).